# How to get the rows that are an error with their latest sequence?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The objective is to get the rows that are an error with their latest sequence. sample data as follows, Temptable is used since it useful for further transactions

[image]

here is my query

```
SELECT MAX(cc.[sequence]) [sequence], 
       OrderID, 
       OrderItemID
INTO #tmpErrorRecords
FROM [TMC].CVOrderCompletions cc
WHERE cc.[status] = 0
      AND LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(errorMessage, ''))) <> ''
GROUP BY cc.OrderID, 
         cc.OrderItemID;
```

My lead reviews the above query and says, There is still going to be a bug in the way you are selecting the error rows in the temp table. I have revised the code that selects the error rows and it should look like below.
But I'm wondering what is the difference between the above and the revised query? Appreciate if somebody could help me with this please

```
 SELECT MAX(cc.[sequence]) [sequence], 
       OrderID, 
       OrderItemID
INTO #tmpOCRecords
FROM TMC.CVOrderCompletions cc
GROUP BY cc.OrderID, 
         cc.OrderItemID;
SELECT cc.[sequence], 
       cc.OrderID, 
       cc.OrderItemID
INTO #tmpErrorRecords
FROM TMC.CVOrderCompletions cc
     INNER JOIN #tmpOCRecords tc ON(cc.OrderID = tc.OrderID
                                    AND cc.OrderItemID = tc.OrderItemID
                                    AND cc.[sequence] = tc.[sequence]
                                    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(cc.errorMessage, ''))) != ''
                                    AND cc.STATUS = 0);
```

Comment: If someone thought there was a bug, why would he not have told you what he suspected it was? Sounds like a pretty useless lead...

Comment: So you deleted your previous question and posted again. Do you NOT think you will receive similar comments?

Answer (score 0):

What your lead could/should have told you is that `cc.[status] = 0` is not going to fetch any rows for the shown sample data...

What defines an error row? *It has an error message.*

This is the only filter you need. Do not overcomplicate things.

**Sample data**

(Text data that can be copy-pasted instead of images next time, please!)

```
create table tmpErrors
(
  id int,
  orderId int,
  orderItemId int,
  sequence int,
  status int,
  errorMessage nvarchar(100)
);

insert into tmpErrors (id, orderId, OrderItemId, sequence, status, errorMessage) values
( 1, 1136832, 1, 0, 1, null),
( 2, 1136832, 1, 1, 1, null),
( 3, 1142898, 1, 0, 1, 'Sql procedure ...'),
( 4, 1142898, 1, 1, 1, 'Sql procedure ...'),
( 5, 1142898, 1, 2, 1, 'Sql procedure ...'),
( 6, 1142898, 1, 3, 1, 'Sql procedure ...'),
( 7, 1142904, 1, 0, 1, null),
( 8, 1142910, 1, 0, 1, 'Invoice record ...'),
( 9, 1142910, 1, 1, 1, 'Invoice record ...'),
(10, 1142910, 1, 2, 1, 'Invoice record ...'),
(11, 1142916, 1, 0, 1, null);
```

**Solution**

```
select te.orderId,
       te.orderItemId,
       max(te.sequence) as sequence
from tmpErrors te
where te.errorMessage is not null
group by te.orderId,
         te.orderItemId;
```

**Result**

```
orderId orderItemId sequence
------- ----------- --------
1142898 1           3
1142910 1           2
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1763782869152f2c4c2c997a08c17883) to see things in action.